# Authenticate popup with Selenium (Java) with out using wait

Tags: java, selenium

How to pass the credentials in the pop up while requesting any http application URL ???

with out using wait

driver.get("http://username:password@site URL");

Comment: With out having wait, which requires exception handling

Answer (score -1):

The code below worked for me.

```
driver.get("http://username:password@application URL");
```